# How can I fetch multiple rows from MySQL and display individually in view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, fetch

I want to fetch multiple rows in view but not as array() instead individually in different container.I searched different codes but all fails, I used following code to fetch data individually but got error `Undefined Variable: row`

```
  <?php $query = $this->db->get("content");
 for($i=1;$i <= $query -> num_rows(); ++$i){
 $data[$i]['c_id'] = $query -> $row($i) -> c_id;
 $data[$i]['con'] = $query -> $row($i)-> c_content;
 $data[$i]['img'] = $query -> $row($i)-> c_image;
 $data[$i]['link'] = $query -> $row($i)-> c_link;
 $data[$i]['heading'] = $query -> $row($i)-> c_heading;
     } 
// for echo 3rd value of data row
echo $data[3]['con'];  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$` from `$row($i)`; Its `row()` that you need to use:

```
<?php
 $query = $this->db->get("content");
 for($i=0;$i < $query->num_rows(); ++$i){
 $data[$i]['c_id'] = $query->row($i)->c_id;
 $data[$i]['con'] = $query->row($i)->c_content;
 $data[$i]['img'] = $query->row($i)->c_image;
 $data[$i]['link'] = $query->row($i)->c_link;
 $data[$i]['heading'] = $query->row($i)->c_heading;
     } 
// for echo 3rd value of data row
echo $data[3]['con'];  
?>
```